# Select N elements from each partition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Assuming that I am having a RDD. I set number of partitions of RDD to 5. I want to select **10** elements from each partition and want to store them in a variable called **var1** and later I want to broadcast **var1**. How can I achieve this?

If I use that will lead to huge data shuffling so I could use collect. I have to store selected elements from each partition in a variable. Also consider that this is an iterative problem and I have to broadcast after **X** specified iterations.

Answer (score 0):

you can try getting partition number using `.mapPartitionsWithIndex`, grouping by partition using `.groupBy`, adding id with `.zipWithIndex`, then filtering up to 10 records for each group with `.filter` and finally `.collect`.

Comment: can not use collect() as this will lead to higher communication overhead

Answer (score 0):

> Apply take(n) function to each partition of the RDD, which will
>   produce another RDD with n*noOfPartitions items.

```
val var1 = rdd.mapPartitions(rows  => rows.take(10)).collect()
```

> Note: Here collect is happening in resultant RDD which should be much
>   smaller than original RDD(provided n is small enough).